# How to enforce ASP .NET application access through a common gateway?

Tags: asp.net

**Background**

At my work we are moving from desktop applications to web applications. Our ASP .NET web applications (not website) use .NET Framework 2.0 and run on IIS 7.0.

**Environment Overview**

We want to have one Root application and several web applications which satisfy specific business needs. For example, ***Root***, ***Application A***, ***Application B*** and ***Application C***. On the Root application we will display links to all the applications the user has access to. We are using Windows Authentication and managing a table of application specific access levels (on our SQL Server 2008 database).

**Question**

One of our goals is to enforce the user to access their applications from the **Root** application only. That is, we do not want them to bookmark http://AppServer/Root/ApplicationA and access **Application A** by visiting the bookmark. We rather want them to go to http://AppServer/Root and click on the link to **Application A** to access it.

How can we achieve this? I only need a high-level idea here.

Many thanks to anyone who gives it a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the gateway, launch the applications via a form post that uses some sort of expiring token. The token cannot be saved in the bookmark, and if users hit the app without a token, redirect them to the gateway. The token can only be generated by the gateway app but validated by the child apps. Once a user has validated in a child app, you can store a session variable to allow them access to the other parts of the app.

Comment: I was thinking of creating a SessionID from the gateway and appending it to the request to the applications. And then put some code in the application to check if the SessionID is active. I think you're saying something similar, but in a more organized manner, lolz. Will take the route you said. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Check referer field of http requests.

Comment: Probably fine in corporateland, but users can mangle this field or even switch it off altogether.